# Is there a jquery plugin that columnizes list items horizontally rather than vertically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, layout

I'm looking for a jquery plugin or javascript that will columnize a list.
I've seen [Columizer](http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/), which is great and the configuration options are just what I need, except that it doesn't columnize data in the direction I need.

My list:

```
1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6. 7. 8. 9.
```

Columizer behavior I want:

```
1. 2. 3.
4. 5. 6.
7. 8. 9.
```

Columizer behavior I **don't** want:

```
1. 4. 7.
2. 5. 8.
3. 6. 9.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably achieve this with CSS.

Assuming the list is in < ul>< li> format:

```
{
  display:inline-block;
  width:33%;
}
```

or use float:left; and then set clear:all; on every third one.

or something like that -- there's probably about a dozen ways to do this in CSS.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a jQuery plugin for that. Simply set the float property for the `<li>`s:

```
li {
    float: left;
}
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/FgZ9N/

Answer (score 1):

If you mean displaying list items in that fashion, no scripting is requried. setting a width on each list item, giving the list container element a width equal to the total columns, and using 'float:left' should do the trick

Comment: Because the listed items are of variable height, when I float them one item will occasionally get "caught" beneath a short item above it, causing a row with only one item in it. To fix this I've used display:table cell but that isn't ideal.

Comment: how about setting clear:both on every last list item in a row? either while generating server side or using nth-child property?